# Why doesn't my gulp-uncss task, strip out unused css?

Tags: gulp

I try to pipe my sass files first, from my dev environment and then into production. But when I test it by leaving a unassigned class it still remains in my production css code.

```js
.task('usemin', function(){
  gulp.src('builds/development/*.html')
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production',usemin({
      css: [minifycss(), 'concat'],
      js: [uglify()],
      html:[minifyHTML()]

      // in this case css will be only concatenated (like css: ['concat']).
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('builds/production/'));
});



gulp.task('uncss', function() {
        return gulp.src('builds/development/css/main.css')
        .pipe(uncss({
            html: ['builds/production/index.html', 'builds/production/work.html', 'builds/production/contact.html']
        }))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('builds/production/css/main.css'));
});


//sass task
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src(sassSources)
      .pipe(sass({
        style: sassStyle,sourcemapPath: false,sourcemap:false
      }))
       .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
      .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); })
      .pipe(gulp.dest('builds/development/css/'))
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe( notify({ message: "Sass tasks have been completed!"}) );
});
```

Comment: I don't see any dependencies between `uncss` and `usemin`, are you sure the production html files are being generated before `uncss` is running?  Can you provide examples of how you are defining the css that isn't being removed?